# Head pointer keeps changing position in linked lists

Tags: c

I am having some trouble with this piece of code. When i try printing the list after adding to the list, it just prints the last element.

*list, *temp and *new_node are declared locally.

```
if(list == NULL && new_node != NULL){
        fprintf(fp1, "\r\nNew node1: %s %s %d %ld %d", new_node->op, new_node->name, new_node->tag, new_node->msgsize, new_node->weight);
        list = (struct  vertex*)malloc(sizeof(struct vertex));
        list->name = new_node->name;
        list->next = NULL;
        list_of_vertices[rank] = list;
        printf("changin list head\n");
        //temp = list->next;
    }
    else{
        if(new_node != NULL){
            temp = list;
            while(temp){
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp = (struct vertex*)malloc(sizeof(struct vertex));
            temp->name = new_node->name;
            temp->next = NULL;
            fprintf(fp1, "\r\nNew node: %s %s %d %ld %d", temp->op, temp->name, temp->tag, temp->msgsize, temp->weight);
        }
    }
```

Edit: The following piece of code doesn't work either. It changes the value of list everytime but i enter into the if condition to set list only once.

```
while(!feof(fp)){
    fgets(read_line, 100, fp);
    /*new node created by tokenizing string */
    if(list == NULL && new_node != NULL){
        fprintf(fp1, "\r\nNew node1: %s %s %d %ld %d", new_node->op, new_node->name, new_node->tag, new_node->msgsize, new_node->weight);
        list = (struct  vertex*)malloc(sizeof(struct vertex));
        list->name = new_node->name;
        list->next = NULL;
        printf("list head\n %s", list->op); //prints only once when first line from file read
    }
    if(list != NULL)
        printf("list head changed\n %s", list->name); // prints the name from the current read line.
}
```

Comment: What is your `while()` loop supposed to be doing??

Comment: There's a lot of code in this example that appears to have nothing to do with your problem. Yet you don't show how you try to print the list (I see only one node printed in this code) or how you keep track of it in between adding nodes. Try writing the smallest possible program that shows the thing that doesn't work, so we can concentrate on that question.

Comment: When you get out of the `while` loop, `temp` is NULL. After that, no matter what you do to `temp`, it does not get connected to `list`. You are merely allocating memory for `temp` which is lost to the program.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Fixed the issue. I was not copying the string values, instead was using the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue. I was not copying the string values, instead was using the pointer(i.e. a = b instead of strcpy(a, b) where a and b are char arrays)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
while(temp){
  temp = temp->next;
}

temp = (struct vertex*)malloc(sizeof(struct vertex));
```

to

```
while(temp->next){
  temp = temp->next;
}

temp->next = (struct vertex*)malloc(sizeof(struct vertex));
temp = temp->next;
```

Comment: That aside, you could easily copy every member of `new_node` to `temp` just using `*temp = *new_node` (supposing they are both of the same type). Beware that every single member will get copied, even the `next` pointer, for example.

Comment: Also, as an extended advice to the above comment, look if you can use `new_node` directly (instead of copying it to `temp`): that way to append a new element to the list would just be a matter of `temp->next = new_node` (instead of `malloc`).

Comment: The problem here is that the beginning of my list gets moved everytime.

Comment: @annm1991 I can't see how. If I understood it correctly, `list` is the head of your list. It is only assigned once, at `list = (...)malloc(...)`.

Comment: yes, that's right and I am not assigning it a value anywhere else.